# How can I run docker on diskless machines?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, docker

I want to run docker on diskless Ubuntu 16.04.

I setted up PXE server and could run diskless ubuntu referring [here](http://shitwefoundout.com/wiki/Diskless_ubuntu).
But when I run `docker run --rm hello-world`, the diskless machine returned following messages.

```
[1731.173432] overlayfs: filesystem on '/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0fdffd6d...76-init/diff' not supported as upperdir
docker: Error response from daemon: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/870b3f2dd200854c747c16abae84e22bf42506cc0aba0fa183205165a83462d5-init/merged: invalid argument.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I searched this error and understood that the docker is using 'overlay2' as filesystem and the 'overlay2' is not supporting nfs filesystem I used.

Could someone help me to use docker on the diskless machines?

Comment: Please delete your duplicate question on SO: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398304/how-can-i-run-docker-on-diskless-machines

Answer (score 4):

[NFS is not supported](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15239#issuecomment-246111523) for the [graph data in Docker](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21531#issuecomment-204184490).

It [should be possible to run Docker entirely from a ramdisk](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10490) if you set the `DOCKER_RAMDISK` environment variable and point the Docker daemon to use it `dockerd -g /path/to/ramdisk`

If you have any other way of exporting a block device to your PXE booted machine, do that and use that device as a [`direct-lvm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#configure-direct-lvm-mode-for-production) store for the [devicemapper](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/) storage driver. [nbd](https://nbd.sourceforge.io/), [iSCSI](http://linux-iscsi.sourceforge.net/), maybe [Ceph](http://ceph.com/ceph-storage/block-storage/).

The only way I can see NFS might work is Oracle Linux has(had?) a [dm-nfs](https://blogs.oracle.com/wim/dm-nfs) kernel driver that [can be used](https://blogs.oracle.com/otn/how-to-treat-an-nfs-file-as-a-block-storage-device) to make devicemapper loopback files faster than they would be if you mounted the loopback file over NFS normally. Loopback files aren't great for Docker on local disk so I expect over NFS would have a good probability of being horrible.

Answer (score 1):

I could find how to use docker on NFS somehow.
Use aufs instead of overlay2.

You should stop the docker service by `sudo systemctl stop docker`. Then,
edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as follows, and run the docker again by `sudo systemctl start docker`.

```
{
  "storage-driver": "aufs"
}
```

Comment: Have you used it to run container yet? Docker might run but you might get a lot more aufs issues in Docker than normal.

Comment: Currently, I don't get any issues from using it. But I'm not familiar with such kind of job (diskless server and others). Could you teach me why it will cause problems?